# How do i read and print information from two files?

Tags: c, file, struct

My class, my teacher and I all couldn't figure out what's wrong with the code. It's a canteen ordering system, so as a student you order something and it logs it into a system and the canteen workers can make food accordingly. The specific problem is that I'm trying to make a tally but it only prints the first food item that was ordered. The relevant code is below and images are attached.

[Menu of available items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8ykg.png),
[Orders Placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR7zC.png), [Result of order tally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiZNC.png) //note the student's order is an ID of the food item

```
struct food
{

    int   foodID;

    char  foodName[namesize];//namesize is 30

    char  foodItems[size];//specials for the day//size is 3

    int   itemTally;//total of food that needs to be prepared - REPLACED

    float totalEarnt;//total amount earnt for selling the food

    float totalSpen;//cost of food to the employer

    float totalProfits;//total profts made

    float itemCost;//cost of the food item

};

struct student
{

    char  firstname[namesize];

    char  lastname[namesize];

    int   ID;//students ID

    float form;//student's form room

    int   order;//ID of the food they ordered

    int   quantity;//how much of the food item

    float paid;//how much they paid

    int   delivery;//This is a yes or no

    char  location[aSize];//where it will be delivered to; aSize is 20

};

void orderTally()//Tallies up all the orders based on their ID; Student 1 orders 3 fish, student 2 orders 4 fish, outputs 7 fish
{

    FILE*fp;
    FILE*fp1;

    struct food foodie={0,"","",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    struct student orderie={"","",0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0,""};
    int i;//This is the food ID.

    if((fp1 = fopen("student", "rb+"))==NULL)//order file
    {
        printf("Cannot open order file \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((fp = fopen("food", "rb+"))==NULL)//menu file
    {
        printf("Cannot open food file \n");//UPDATE: update other statements
        exit(1);
    }
    int sum=0;

    for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
    {
        fread(&orderie,sizeof(struct student),1,fp1);

        while(!feof(fp1))
        {
            if(orderie.order==i)//If the order ID is equal to one of the 100 food IDs...
            {   
                sum=sum+orderie.quantity;
            }
            fread(&orderie,sizeof(struct student),1,fp1);
        }
        if(sum!=0)
        {
            fseek(fp,(i-1)*sizeof(struct food),SEEK_SET);
            fread(&foodie,sizeof(struct food),1,fp);

            printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("\t\t\tORDERS\n");
            printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
            printf("%s",foodie.foodName);
            printf(" - %d\n\n",sum);
            sum=0;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Read this:  [**Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)  Your instructor missing that is disappointing.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTIONS: 1) Save and check the return status of *EACH* I/O operation (fread(), fseek(), etc). 2) Consider changing `while(!feof(...))` to `while ((iret = fread(...))` (or equivalent).  And, MOST IMPORTANT: 3) Step through the debugger.  Please post back what you find, and/or update your post with any specific questions you encounter along the way.

Comment: Even better, quit cramming too much code into your `if` statements.  You can't single-step through `if ((fp = fopen("food", "rb+"))==NULL)` like you can `fp = fopen("food", "rb+");` followed by `if (fp == NULL)` **on a separate line**.  That also makes your code a **LOT** easier to understand.  You gain nothing by cramming the assignment into the `if`-statement - other than too much going on in each line for a beginner in C to understand.

Comment: You are doing `for (i=1;i<=100;i++)` and the first part of that loop is doing `fread` on the _entire_ contents of `fp1` [in the `while` loop]. So, when `i` is 2, the `fread` will get an immediate EOF. Do you need an `fseek` for `fp1` [to rewind it] on each iteration of the `for` loop? If not, the `while` for `fp1` would be better placed _above_ the `for` loop. As it is, it seems wasteful to reread the file 100 times.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - technically the use of `while(!feof(fp1))` is okay here because it is called *After* the attempted read and *Before* the content of `orderie` are accessed -- looks wonky, but technically fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comment:

> You are doing `for (i=1;i<=100;i++)` and the first part of that loop is doing `fread` on the entire contents of `fp1` [in the `while` loop]. So, when `i` is 2, the `fread` will get an immediate EOF. Do you need an `fseek` for `fp1` [to rewind it] on each iteration of the `for` loop? If not, the `while` for `fp1` would be better placed above the for loop. As it is, it seems wasteful to reread the file 100 times.

I've restructured and simplified things a bit. It's a *lot* easier to read the student file once and record *all* sums in an array.

```
struct food {
    int foodID;
    char foodName[namesize];            // namesize is 30
    char foodItems[size];               // specials for the day//size is 3
    int itemTally;                      // total of food that needs to be prepared - REPLACED
    float totalEarnt;                   // total amount earnt for selling the food
    float totalSpen;                    // cost of food to the employer
    float totalProfits;                 // total profts made
    float itemCost;                     // cost of the food item
};

struct student {
    char firstname[namesize];
    char lastname[namesize];
    int ID;                             // students ID
    float form;                         // student's form room
    int order;                          // ID of the food they ordered
    int quantity;                       // how much of the food item
    float paid;                         // how much they paid
    int delivery;                       // This is a yes or no
    char location[aSize];               // where it will be delivered to; aSize is 20
};

// Tallies up all the orders based on their ID; Student 1 orders 3 fish,
// student 2 orders 4 fish, outputs 7 fish
void
orderTally()
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp1;

    struct food foodie;
    struct student orderie;
    int i;                              // This is the food ID.

    // order file
    if ((fp1 = fopen("student", "rb+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open order file \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int sums[101] = { 0 };

    // read _entire_ student file in one pass
    while (1) {
        if (fread(&orderie,sizeof(struct student),1,fp1) != 1)
            break;
        sums[orderie.order] += orderie.quantity;
    }

    fclose(fp1);

    // menu file
    if ((fp = fopen("food", "rb+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open food file \n"); // UPDATE: update other statements
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        int sum = sums[i];
        if (sum == 0)
            continue;

        fseek(fp, (i - 1) * sizeof(struct food), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&foodie, sizeof(struct food), 1, fp);

        printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\t\t\tORDERS\n");
        printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
        printf("%s", foodie.foodName);
        printf(" - %d\n\n", sum);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```